# Magento 2 UI Component

Tags: admin, grid, uicomponent, magento2.3

I need to customize **admin grid** which is in `Content->Pages`.

What is the correct way to add new **`feature/customize`** to the **admin grid**?

Suppose in the above-mentioned **grid**, I need to change the **"Add New Page"** to **"Add Pages"**

Thanks

Comment: did it work? di you find it? hows the tip below, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can override **`vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml`**

With your custom module, through the path:

> app/code/vendor/module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml

From there you can change,

```
<label translate="true">Add New Page</label>
```

To

```
<label translate="true">Add Pages</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

@magefms is right but you can also do it other way using translation way.

CSV file is located at:

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/i18n/en_US.csv

Then need the following changes: Add New Page => Add Pages

Then run below command

> php bin/magento c:f
>   php bin/magento c:c

[Click here for more refrance](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-translation/)

I hope it helps!